# What is the best BigQuery Load Data Source Type? - Data ETL

Tags: google-bigquery

What is the best data source type for loading data into Bigquery?

eg. csv, csv.gz, parquet, orc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [document](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/bigquery-explained-data-ingestion) when optimizing for load speed, Avro file format is preferred.

As for the other formats:

- Parquet and ORC load slower than the Avro format.
- Compressed CSV and JSON are slower than Uncompressed CSV and JSON. Highly parallel load operations allow uncompressed files to load significantly faster than compressed files.Compressed files are faster to transmit and cheaper to store, but slower to load into BigQuery.

**In a nutshell:**
Avro(Compressed/Uncompressed) > Parquet / ORC > CSV >JSON >CSV(compressed) >JSON(compressed).